# What alternatives are there for asp.net forms authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, forms-authentication

We are developing a web app that will have a pretty complex user and permission system.

The general idea is that we have 3 levels of security:

- a simple user - that can only access basic data that is in a data repository
- a manager - that can open up data repositories
- a superuser - that can open up repository factories.

each repository contains various data types(text, images, etc etc).

We are looking for authentication methods that will allow us:
1. Scalability.
2. Customization.
3. To create permissions that will effect the GUI + deny access to certain pages.
4. To create predefined roles - that will allow for easy setup of new users.
5. To create custom roles for specific users - allowing them permission sets that are different from the predefined roles.

Thanks in advance

Comment: why do you need alternative, are you using mysql as back-end server

Comment: @volody - i am looking for alternatives because asp.net build in security seems full of features i don't need, and i fear that it will waste a lot of our time on bugs and features we need that don't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do everything you require using the built-in ASP.NET Membership, Roles, and Profile functionality.  I recommend checking out Scott Mitchell's [excellent series of articles](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202857/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx) on how to use and customize this functionality.

Comment: thanks a lot, we decided using the asp.net forms authentication.

Answer (score 3):

What you are telling in this post is an exact description of the type of thing granted by the ASP.NET Membership system, why not use it?

Answer (score 0):

It does sound like the existing framework would work, or that you could create a custom membership/roles provider to add some of the existing features you are looking for. It depends on the requirement details.